# I need to relate strings of implications.

Tags: logic

Let's say we have a string of implications $p_0\Rightarrow p_1\Rightarrow\cdots\Rightarrow p_n$. What can be said about $p_n\Rightarrow p_{n-1}\Rightarrow\cdots\Rightarrow p_0$ from the original string of implications?

My intent here is to simplify a truth table with a purposeful lemma, where I have the outputs for a string of implications $a\Rightarrow b\Rightarrow c\Rightarrow \cdots$, from which I wish to relate $e\Rightarrow d\Rightarrow c\Rightarrow \cdots$ to.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is conventional to interpret $\;a\Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c\;$ as $\;a \Rightarrow (b\Rightarrow c)\;$, which is equivalent to $\;\neg (a\wedge b)\vee c\;$.

Thus $\;p_0 \Rightarrow p_1 \Rightarrow\cdots\Rightarrow p_{n-1} \Rightarrow p_n\;$ is equivalent to $\;\neg (p_0\wedge p_1 \wedge \cdots\wedge p_{n-1})\vee p_n\;$.

Likewise $\;p_n \Rightarrow p_{n-1} \Rightarrow\cdots\Rightarrow p_1 \Rightarrow p_0\;$ is equivalent to $\;\neg (p_n\wedge p_{n-1} \wedge \cdots\wedge p_1)\vee p_0\;$.

So, by knowing one you cannot really say much about the converse.

---

Note that implication is not associative, so $\;a\Rightarrow (b\Rightarrow c)\;$ is *not equivalent* to $\;(a\Rightarrow b)\Rightarrow c\;$.